# Google maps location inaccurate by over 200 miles

Tags: google, maps

My phone keeps recording me as being over 200 miles south of where I am. I have looked up the location but it is not anywhere I have ever visited, Godalming near Epsom. When looking on my history it records me as being there more than once, however zooming in to that location it is actually just a track down a back Road. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts, Anna! Please see [these related questions with answers](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=google+maps+wrong+location+answers%3A1). Afraid the only thing *you* can do to prevent this is turning off location services altogether.

Answer (score 0):

try checking if you have a vpn(virtual private network) running in the background. This can change your location far away from your actual place. Also make sure that you turned the location on to high accuracy. This will make it so that it google maps checks for location using your WiFi and data as well, in case the GPS in your phone is broken. It may also be that google maps can't register the specific location you are at. Check other locations and if all else fails try [reading these related questions with answers](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=google%20maps%20wrong%20location%20answers%3A1)  or check the [google maps support page](https://support.google.com/maps/?hl=en#topic=3093612)     . Here are also some [alternatives](http://geoawesomeness.com/5-alternative-apps-hate-new-google-maps/) to google maps. It would be good to know which device you are using to further troubleshoot the problem.